# Как беcплатно разослать смс пользователям?

Tags: php, sms, рассылка

Добрый день. У меня в бд есть номера телефонов пользователей. Есть ли бесплатный сервис рассылки смс ?
Как это настроить на php?

Comment: ох уж эта непобедимая любовь к халяве

Answer (score 4):

За исходящую смс вам так или иначе придется заплатить. Можно найти рассыльщиков с разной ценой, уровнем сервиса (статистика и т.д.) и возможностью интеграции. Как правило, у них есть четкий ответ на вопрос "как настроить"в виде соответствующего FAQ и API. Это самый простой вариант. Такого рода услуги может предоставлять как сам оператор сотовой связи, так и сторонние организации.
Бывают варианты использования дыр в веб-интерфейсах операторов, но варианты эти кривы и недолговечны. Также можно подключить свою старую мобилку, и платить за нее =)